# QCandlestickSet is undefined C++ Qt5.15

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt5

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community x64, Qt version 5.15.2. I have the 'Charts' module installed and selected in Project ->  Properties -> Qt Project Settings -> Qt Modules

My code:

```
#include <QCandlestickSet>

struct Bar
{
    double open, close, high, low;
    qint64 timestamp;

    Bar() : open(0.0), close(0.0), high(0.0), low(0.0), timestamp(0)
    {
    }

    QCandlestickSet * toCandle(void)
    {
        return new QCandlestickSet(this->open, this->high, this->low, this->close, this->timestamp);
    }
};
```

I am getting the error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "QCandlestickSet" is undefined   ProjectName ..\Bar.h    27

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a *full* and *complete* copy-paste of the error.

Comment: From what I recall `QtCharts` has its own namespace.  Try `QtCharts::QCandlestickSet` .

Comment: Thank you - added 'using QtCharts::QCandlestickSet;' Compiled fine - I didn't see the namespace in the QCandlestickSet documentation, if it's there.

Comment: That's in fact confusing. Qt doc. doesn't mention it: [QCandleStickSet](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcandlestickset.html#details). Looking into the source (on woboq.org) provides a bit more info: [qcandlestickset.h](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/candlestickchart/qcandlestickset.h.html#QtCharts::QCandlestickSet). Please, note the `QT_CHARTS_BEGIN_NAMESPACE` in line 37. Clicking it, I ended up in [qchartglobal.h](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/qchartglobal.h.html#62). It seems that it depends on whether `QT_CHARTS_NAMESPACE` is defined...

Comment: ...and this seems to be defined always [#ifndef Q_CLANG_QDOC](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/qchartglobal.h.html#57). (Confusing...) ;-)

Comment: Finally, I found the resp. hint in the doc. as well: [Qt Charts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html): _If you intend to use Qt Charts C++ classes in your application, use the following include and using directives: `#include <QtCharts>` `using namespace QtCharts;`_

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it in the QtCharts section of the documentation - that will teach me to implement the candlestick support code prior to creating a chart :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by G.M., everything QtChart related is held within a namespace called QtCharts.

Doing any of the following will fix this issue:

```
using QtCharts::QCandlestickSet;
```

OR

```
using namespace QtCharts;
```

OR

```
QtCharts::QCandlestickSet * toCandle(void)
{
    return new QtCharts::QCandlestickSet(this->open, this->high, this->low, this->close, this->timestamp);
}
```

Although the namespace is not mentioned in the page relating to QCandlestickSet, it is mentioned on the [QtCharts page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html)